# Should you chose gTLD rather then ccTLD even you're not targeting your market to global?

Tags: seo, domains, top-level-domains, marketing, cctld

So let's say you're starting a project, you wish it could be used internationally. But currently, in the development stage, you're developing mainly for local user (easier for marketing). Then in this case, should you chose ccTLD (your local ccTLD) or gTLD (.com, .cc, .design)?

Comment: Why not buy both? You will then have time to learn and see the traffic and ranking of each, based on your own specific content. Also `.CC` is a ccTLD, it is the country "Cocos Island", see https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/cc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.com domains seem to succeed on an international level. If you use your nation's tld you're likely to generate more traffic from that country especially if you target it in webmaster console. .design and .cc domains tend not to rank as high in Google search as a .com would, though the .design and .cc domains allow you to have a keyword rich domain which still gives you a slight ranking boost, though not as large as it once did. Tlds of a specific nation rarely rank outside of their country, which makes me wonder why they are generally popular unless the website actually doesn't want traffic from other nations.

Comment: I think the picture is a little more complicated than your ".COM rules" feeling, which you do not back up with any substantative facts.